# Can anyone guide how can I add shadow effect to Grid in windows universal app?

Tags: win-universal-app

[add shadow effect to Grid in windows universal app like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrbts.png)

Comment: In XAML or HTML UWP application?

Comment: In XAML UWP application

Comment: in this case I'm afraid you can only use trick that was purposed by LovetoCode. Shadow effect in XAML UWP is not implemented yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
<Grid  >

            <Rectangle Width="230" Height="225" Margin="1,1,0,0" Stroke="#99000000" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Rectangle Width="230" Height="225" Margin="2,2,0,0" Stroke="#4C000000" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Rectangle Width="230" Height="225" Margin="3,3,0,0" Stroke="#19000000" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have HTML/JS UWP application then you can try to use CSS style

```
box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
```